# Cannot open Android studio project after install kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin

Just downloaded Android Studio 2.3.3 and after install I've created a simple project. Then I've installed Kotlin plugin and now I cannot open projects...

This is the error message:

```
Cannot load project:
```

`com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: com.intellij.diagnostic.PluginException: org/jetbrains/android/uipreview/AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager [Plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.dsl]`

(SOLVED)
I don't know why but after reinstall kotlin plugin and restart android studio several times magically it works..

Thank you all

Comment: Are you using latest version of Kotlin plugin ? Since it was a issue in the kotlin's pervious version, If not, just disable the kotlin plugin your project will work again. This error is mainly occurs when one of your plugin is not compatible.

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the lastest version of Kotlin (I cannot update). But I dont want to disable plugin because I want to use Kotlin in the project and also I cannot create new projects.

Comment: For better Kotlin support try Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7+. Those are good enough and stable enough more over you can keep your Android Studio 2.3.3 installation no need to replace.

Comment: Faced same problem. Try to make new project with kotlin dependency. (  While creating project check kotlin dependency ). It will download remaining kotlin support. Now you will be able to use android studio for older project.

Comment: @JoseLuis Have you added Kotlin's classpath to your project Build.gradle and Kotlin's plugin in your module.gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same problem when I was creating New Project in Android Studio. I get an error "com.intellij.diagnostic Pluginexception Plugin org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.dsl"

**Solution :**

Go to "Welcome Android Studio" > Configure > Plugin > Search "Anko" plugin. Uninstall this plugin and Restart the Android Studio.

This fixed for me.